# Can't display a base64 decoded Image in a FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I neeed help displaying a base64 decoded image in my FirebaseListAdapter.

This is the code FirebaseListAdapter I'm using, but it crashes my app, I'm not sure which way to do it correctly.

All my variables are correct and it is retrieving the base64 String, correctly.

```
      sAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Status>(this, Status.class, R.layout.user_status_list, sRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, Status status, int position) {

            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.status_txt)).setText(status.getStatusTxt());
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.username_txt)).setText(status.getAuthorUsername());



            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(status.getAuthorImg(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            statusImg.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);


    }
    };
    statusList.setAdapter(sAdapter);

}
```

Comment: add your logcat output so we can see the crash detail

Comment: Sure, thanks for considering helping me... http://i.stack.imgur.com/LTRCl.png

Comment: shows null pointer at line HomeActivity.92 . you need to tell that line

Comment: statusImg.setImageBitmap(decodeByte);      is located on 92 and   sAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Status>(this, Status.class, R.layout.user_status_list, sRef) { on 82

Comment: how are you storing the base 64 image in fireimage ?

Comment: I created a base64 string from a method and uploaded the strings to firebase. http://i.stack.imgur.com/4EIv3.png

Comment: I tested if the single method for retrieving the base64 would work outside the adapter, and it retrieved it successfully, but it unfortunately doesn´t work that way inside the FirebaseListAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused because i was casting the `ImageView` privately `onCreate` as a private variable (to access any method inside the class). Which `statusImg` was.

So instead, I casted it inside the method within this line.

This is the non-working way to use the line.

```
statusImg.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

This will instead cast the `ImageView` inside my FirebaseListAdapter, and no longer give me Null pointer.

```
((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.status_img)).setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```